# Configure server to open public/index.php on '/' Laravel Project

Tags: php, laravel, apache, deployment

I'm currently working on deploying a laravel project for the first time. I have succeeded in installing a laravel project on my server but unfortunately, when going to the website no laravel page is shown. My `.htaccess` file in the root directory:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]

    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?mydomain.nl$
    RewriteRule ^(/)?$ public [L]
</IfModule>
```

Could someone please help me with this issue?

Comment: what is the error you receive?

Comment: Anna Jeanine what is the URL ?
For a better explanation of the rules you could test it against URL directly using https://htaccess.madewithlove.be/

Please let us know the full URL.

Comment: No error is shown but the sever hosting logo is shown. The website is www.badge-borduren.nl.

Comment: set root to project/public folder not the project folder

Comment: What kind of sever is this. Is it a LAMP stack? And where did you get the server (e.g. Digital Ocean, Amazon webservice)?

Comment: Remove the final 3 `Rewrite` lines, and make sure the vhost docroot is set to your `public/` dir.  That's it.

Comment: check the apache logs for more detail. it could help if you gave us a clue what we are looking at here

Answer (score 0):

We do not know about what kind of server this is and where you got it (AWS, Digital Ocean).

Generally you have to move to this directory in your server:

```
/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/laravel.conf
```

Now you open that file using the touch, vi or nano:

```
sudo nano laravel.conf
```

The file should have a similiar content to this one:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>.
    ServerName app.com // your server name
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    # Your Custom folder 
    DocumentRoot /dir/dir/dir/app/public/ // here you need to add your location
    <Directory /dir/dir/dir/app/public/>  // here you need to add your location
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
    Require all granted
</Directory>
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log
</VirtualHost>
```

Now you need to change to location to your app/public location like I did in the sample config file.